# What is the difference in using xinput and synclient for deactivating a touchpad in X

Tags: xorg, udev, touchpad

I have troubles using `xinput --disable` or `--set-prop "Device Enabled"` or `set-prop "Synaptics Off"`.

It seems that `--disable` / `--enable` and `"Device Enabled"` are meant to deactivate the whole device, meaning buttons and touchpad, whereas `"Synaptics Off"` just works on the touchpad.

However, when I want to deactivate the touchpad using udev rules when a USB mouse is attached, neither of those mechanism works.
I then can only use `synclient "TouchpadOff=1"` to deactivate the touchpad.

What is the difference in all those mechanisms, and why does `--disable` / `--enable` work within an X session (even as another user, e.g. root when setting `DISPLAY` and `XAUTHORITY` accordingly), but not when executed by a rule in udev?

Comment: Why synclient does not work anymore: https://who-t.blogspot.com.au/2016/07/why-synclient-does-not-work-anymore.html

Comment: Have a look at those explanations: http://who-t.blogspot.ch/2016/07/why-synclient-does-not-work-anymore.html
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Touchpad_Synaptics

Comment: Why udev, you may go directly with xorg.conf . see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/439528/12209

Comment: @MichaelYoo - what do you mean? I am using that in Mint Xfce to [toggle touchpad on/off](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/627612/341192)